# Pycharm AttributeError dlsym(0x2006bea00, SHA256_init): symbol not found

Tags: python, pycharm, cryptography, attributeerror

I am currently coding a public key (asymmetric) encryption on Pycharm. My enc, dec, key generation functions are working fine. But now my RSA-sign and RSA-ver functions for Digital Signature are not working.

Please see below the error message that I get everytime I try to type the commands. What should I do? I am not getting any underline error in the code itself only this error message.

[image: Error message]

Comment: In the future please copy-paste the error message instead of uploading a screenshot. This is much better for searches.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently because I'm using macOS. I had to rename some of the packages accordingly.

Mainly Crypto was renamed into the following,

```
from Cryptodome
```

to install it , run in terminal `pip3 install pycryptodome`